# replace/fill na values for some specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, replace, row, fillna

df :

```
address        city
BlockOf13thSt  Treasure Isla
Lincoln        Presidio
Duboce Park    Unknown
Twin Peaks     Unknown
Bernal Heights NaN
Holly Courts   Unknown
Ocean Beach    NaN
Maiden Ln      NaN
Avenue N       NaN
```

output

`address        city
BlockOf13thSt  Treasure Isla
Lincoln        Presidio
Duboce Park    San Francisco
Twin Peaks     San Francisco
Bernal Heights San Francisco
Holly Courts   San Francisco
Ocean Beach    San Francisco
Maiden Ln      New York
Avenue N       New York`

is there any syntax in pandas like SQL (IN)??
where address IN (Duboce Park, Twin Peaks, Bernal Heights, Holly Courts/Ocean Beach) and replacing/fillna for 'San Francisco' and 'New York'

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd  
#Replace all those localities with 'San Francisco'. For this we use .isin() function
df.loc[df['address'].isin(pd.Series(['Duboce Park','Twin Peaks','Bernal Heights','Holly Courts','Ocean Beach'])),'city']='San Francisco'

#Replace all NaNs with 'New York' with fillna().
df = df.fillna('New York')

df
Out[47]: 
          address           city
0   BlockOf13thSt  Treasure Isla
1        Lincoln        Presidio
2     Duboce Park  San Francisco
3      Twin Peaks  San Francisco
4  Bernal Heights  San Francisco
5    Holly Courts  San Francisco
6     Ocean Beach  San Francisco
7       Maiden Ln       New York
8        Avenue N       New York
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter your dataframe with required conditions and then fill null values:

```
df[(df.address == 'Duboce Park') | (df.address == 'Twin Peaks') | (df.address =='Bernal Heights') | (df.address == 'Holly Courts') | (df.address == 'Ocean Beach')].fillna('San Francisco')
```

The pipe `|` operator in pandas is like the `OR` separator in `SQL`.

So, for above `address`, NULL was replaced by `San Francisco`.
Do, the same for other address and replace NULL by `New York`.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas df.fillna() should do the trick. Read the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html